# CSS Rounding Works in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm having an issue with some CSS I'm working on. The expected content is to be a containing box with four rounded corners that everything falls into. It works in Safari on the Mac, but not in Chrome or in iOS. In those browsers, the corners are squared for the .posttype and the image. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue. Any help will be great.

**CSS:**

```css
.row { margin-bottom: 50px; }
.box { background: #eee; }
.shadow { -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #666; box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #666; }
.rounded { border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; display: block; overflow: hidden; }
.posttype {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: -85px -85px 4px 4px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.posttype > p { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.meta {
    width: 110%;
    margin: 5px -8px -8px -8px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: inset -5px 1px 5px #555;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #555;
}
.photo { position: relative; }
.photo > p { padding: 0 8px; }
.photo > .meta { padding-left: 16px; padding-bottom: 16px; }
.photo > img, .photo > a > img { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.photo > .posttype { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; margin: -75px -75px 4px 4px; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span7 box rounded shadow photo">
        <img src="photo.jpg" alt="Alt" width="500">
        <div class="posttype"><p>photo</p></div>
        <p>This is a great picture.</p>
        <hr class="clear">
        <div class="meta">
            <ul>
                <li class="date"><i class="icon-time"></i> <a href="#" title="date">7/29/12</a></li>
                <li class="comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i> 3 Comments</li>
            </ul>
            <hr class="spacer">
            <ul class="tags">
                <li class="tags"><i class="icon-tags"></i></li>
                <li class="tag"><a href="#" title="Tag1">Tag1</a></li>
                <li class="tag"><a href="#" title="Tag2">Tag2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/nvxjO0OL)**

Comment: Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AUv6Z/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The round borders are behind the image, add a `padding-top` look at this http://tinkerbin.com/fLyD5Cuf

Comment: There's also a rounding problem at the bottom.

Comment: Ah. You helped me get to my answer. If I add a `class="rounded"`to the IMG, then I achieve what I'm looking for. I didn't want a padding at the top, but this works. Thank you.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - You're right. The .meta issue still stands. Like the top, I don't want to add padding because I want the meta to round. Adding a .rounded to .meta doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Justin - I don't see how you can do it very cleanly without removing the `background` on the `.meta`. It's overriding the `border-radius`, which is the issue you're having, so the logical answer is to makeup the [`padding` elsewhere](http://jsfiddle.net/AUv6Z/4/). Of course that's not a "great" answer since it defeats the `background-color` for that very bottom padding.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I fixed it. It took a complete rewrite. I gave .photo an overall padding of 8px, and then put the IMG in a new div that has a margin of -8px. It's probably not the cleanest code, but it looks right. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Justin - I knew that would be the case. Without redoing your approach, I couldn't see how it was going to be possible.